# java.lang.NullPointerException when i'm sending data from jsp to servlet

Tags: pointers, exception, null

i'm always getting this exception while i'm running my code.

```
          if((UDID)!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")){ // null pointer exception 
          int id = Integer.parseInt(UDID);
          UserBean user = new UserBean();
          user.setUserdetailid(id);
          user.setUserid(id);
```

Comment: action is null?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Where is `action` assigned?

Comment: Appearently nowhere.

Comment: @KillerDeath is correct. please check your action. it may have null

Comment: @NO_name YOu know that if you put the exception in the edit summary we can't see it easilly right?

Comment: it is in jsp <form action="UserHandler2" method="Post" name="frmadduserdetail">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="insert"/>

Comment: Try if((UDID)!=null && action!=null&&action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")), action is probably reading a null value or not initialised at all

Answer (score 0):

Statement:

```
action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")
```

will throw a nullpointerexception if action == null because you cannot call equalsIgnoreCase method on an unassigned variable.